# How to remove grey highlighting of xml tags in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

In IntelliJ IDEA the XML is highlighted with grey background:

[image]

Is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to *Settings/Editor/Colors and Fonts/Language Defaults*, select *Markup Tag* in the list and uncheck *Background*.

[image]

You might need to save the color scheme using *Save As* first, because you can't modify the default color scheme.

Comment: great, thanks! do most developers found it useful to have background in xml tags?

Comment: @Maximus I don't know, but I doubt it. I think it has no positive effect on code readability. I suggested changing the defaults in this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140381 feel free to add your opinion there so that there's higher chance it will get fixed :)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought)

Comment: Thanks! That should be a default config, no one deserves to read long XML files with little gray squares.